# Paypal dpn не возвращает параметры

Tags: python, paypal, odoo

Столкнулся с проблемой что по указанной ссылке в кнопке Paypal (/payment/paypal/dpn) не возвращаются данные по трансакции. Из-за этого не происходит редиректа на нужную страницу и не чистится корзина заказа.

Настраивал Paypal по инструкции (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/10.0/ecommerce/shopper_experience/paypal.html).

Odoo 8 с последними изменениями (Добавлено PDT вот ссылка https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/payment_paypal/controllers/main.py). IPN работает.

Это проблема происходит и в песочнице, и на продакшн Paypal.

Может быть я что-то не до настроил...

Кто-нибудь может подсказать решение.

Заранее, спасибо.

Comment: А что в вопросе тут по питону?

Comment: Может в коде нужно что-то менять) Я не знаю в чем может быть проблема)

Comment: Может быть в коде... Сложно о чем то говорить, чего не видно :) Но я думаю ваш вопрос нужно адресовать в техподдержку odoo или paypal

Comment: Поэтому есть еще теги Odoo и paypal для этого. Я могу оставит ссылки на последние изменения в коде Odoo. Есть подозрение что это связано с обновлением Paypal api и кто-то уже решал эту проблему. Сейчас поправлю.